# Caculate the standard deviation be for the vatiable in the matrix created by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, std, standard-deviation

```
import tensorflow as tf
input=[50,10]
O1 = layers.fully connected(input, 20, tf.sigmoid)
```

Why my input is wrong?

Comment: Could you try to give some more info about your issue? Simply quoting a piece of code and adding an irrelevant title is not really helpful

Comment: input has a shepe [50,10], O1 = layers.fully connected(input, 20, tf.sigmoid), what will the standard deviation be for the variables in the matrix created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question, but...

The sigmoid layer will output an array with numbers between 0 and 1, but you can't really calculate what the standard deviation will be before feeding your network.

If you are talking about the matrix that contains the weight parameters, then this depends on how you initialize them. But after the training of the network, the deviation will not be the same as before the training.

EDIT:

Ok, so you simply want to calculate the standard deviation for a matrix. In that case see numpy.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) # or your 50 by 50 matrix
np.std(a)
```

Comment: Hi, if the input has a shepe [50,10], and here is a code : O1 = layers.fully connected(input, 20, tf.sigmoid), we can not caculate the standard deviation? I guess there is a function radical sign 1/(50+10),right?

Comment: a [50,10]shaped matrix, the standard deviation

Comment: see latest edit

Comment: x = tf.random.normal(shape=(50,10))
stddev = tfp.stats.stddev(x, sample_axis=0)